# How to document symbol index signature using JSDoc to be typescript compliant?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I am using plain Javascript for creating a class and documenting it using JSDoc and I am using typescript for type checking.

But I cannot figure out how to write a JSDoc properly so it would recognise the field access using a Symbol.

```js
const secret = Symbol('secret');
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    /** @type {Map<string,number>} */
    this[secret] = new Map();
  }
  method() {
    const map = this[secret];
    // Should give an error in the following line since 1 is not a string
    map.set(1, '2');
  }
}
```

The result I get from VSCode is the following (as you can see map has type `any`):
[image: VSCode result]

In TypeScript is pretty easy to make it work, just declare it like any other class property.

```ts
const secret = Symbol('secret');
class MyClass {
  [secret]: Map<string, number>; // Declared here
  constructor() {
    this[secret] = new Map();
  }
  method() {
    const map = this[secret];
    map.set(1, '2');
  }
}
```

The VSCode (typescript) error i get:
[image: VSCode error]

Answer (score -2):

You've `secret` signature as `Map<string, number>;` so `secret` `MUST` have first param as `string` and second param as `number`.

Correct example would be

```
map.set('2',1)
```

Comment: I have Javascript checking enabled in the `tsconfig` file.

Also my problem is about TypeScript not recognising `map.set(1, '2');` as an error not about typescript not working.